# Hosting pages on SVN server

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

I have an SVN server with an URL like https://svn-server.example.com/.

I'd like to host some non-DAV pages on that server.

Because a different host is not possible because of SSL and a different URL for the repositories would require to relocate all working copies (to which I have no access), I tried to set up a certain path for normal pages:

```
<Location /review-board/>
    DAV off
</Location>
```

I found that I apparently cannot do this because it is explicitely denied - they even have an error message for that: `"DAV Off" cannot be used to turn off a subtree of a DAV-enabled location.`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't require SSL for the non DAV pages you can configure you DAV server as a virtual host on *:443.  Then configure your other site as virtual host on *:80.

Alternatively, you can use additional virtual hosts, although you are likely to get certificate address warnings on SSL for the other site.

Comment: "Requiring" SSL is a delicate question, let's say I'd really like to have it. Maybe I'll just live with the certificate warning. However, I heard of a technique of having the Host header in the SSL or TLS handshaking. I have not yet used it but maybe I can configure it in a way that it's transparent for old SVN clients and will avoid the warning in modern browsers?

Comment: Note (not only) to myself: It's called SNI.

Comment: Another possibility is to include the other hostnames as Subject Alternative Name in the certificate.